# Make sure page can only be accessed inside page tab

Tags: php, facebook

I'm building a facebook app that should only be available to users via the facebook page tab.
This means the page may not load when openend outside the facebook page tab.
Is there any way the achieve this via PHP?

I thought of getting the parent url, but since the PHP is loaded inside the iframe I doubt it's even possible... Could go for a Javascript approach but I want to disable the access to the page server-side...

Thanks.

Comment: You could check for the presence of the `signed_request` parameter that gets POSTed to your app on _initial load_ of your app into the iframe. After that, you put the info that you are inside a page tab into the session, so that you will have it available on subsequent pages as well. You could also implement a little JavaScript that checks whether or not the page is loaded in an iframe (checkable just in general, not if so specifically on FB, that’s not possible), and if not, redirect to your page tab on FB.

Comment: The session approach could work... however, all it takes to "brake" the system, is opening the page in the page tab first, leave it open, and open the page not in page tab. The session is still in place so the script assumes it's inside the page tab, while it's not.

Comment: Well then your only other option would be to have each and every in-app link set so that it reloads the whole FB page, using target=_top and the `app_data` parameter for navigation – this way you would get the `signed_request` on every page load. But that’s obviously not the best idea, since it reloads the whole FB page for the user and thereby makes things quite slow. You have to decide, how “important” this really is to you … I mean, what would be the _terrible_ consequences of a user opening your app _outside_ of the FB page …?

Comment: Thanks for your input! I think I'll go with the JS approach.